# Instagram API Using Python - doesn't retrieve data

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I'm playing around with Instagram API using [python-instagram package](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram), and I'm trying some different things that don't seem to work.

I'm using it on my own Instagram profile, after I accepted the app request.

Some things do seem to work - I did get my id, and my comments. This code works (after a few bugs removed, and some scope changing):

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "..."
client_secret = "..."
client_id = "..."

api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
user_id = api.user_search('myusername')[0].id

recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id=user_id, count=10)
for media in recent_media:
    print(media.caption)
```

But - this for example, returns nothing ( ([], None) ):

```
follows = api.user_follows(user_id)
follower = api.user_followed_by(user_id)
print(follower, follows)
```

I'm in sandbox mode - but again, I'm using this on my own Instagram profile after accepting the app's request, so I don't see why Instagram should be against it.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am dealing with the same thing!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568809/accessing-the-username-of-all-the-followers-of-a-user-in-instagram-using-scrapy

Comment: no... I ended up web scraping them. You can do it by looking in the html code and figuring out what needs to be addressed. Or you can also use solaris (If i'm not mistaken) to simulate a web browser and tell it what to do.